# How to fix "#2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) the server is not responding."

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having issues connecting to MySQL server. I go to `localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/?lang=en` and get the error:

> "#2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) the server
>   is not responding."

I've tried many different solutions however, none have worked. If anyone has any advice or ways to fix this, it would be a great help.

Comment: So you already tried all of these suggestions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html?

Comment: I'm using MAMP and I know for a fact that the server is running, I'll check that link shortly, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend restarting your system, and confirming that mysql daemon start with your mamp server properly. You may also try logging into the command line mysql, and observe the configuration. You seem to suggest that you have tried many things, and I assume that you tried restarting. I know it seems ridiculous to ask you to repeat this... but, you want a clean entry point to observe the issue. There may be another mysql server running as well, or it may not be serving where you think it is. By logging into MySql as root, you should be able to determine some of the mis-configuration issues.

Comment: I am still having the same issue with the connection of phpMyAdmin and the MySQL server. I have started the MySQL server through terminal and it tells me "SUCCESS!". I also start the server through MySQL itself and it starts there too, however, MAMP is still saying that MySQL server isn't running; even when the server is started through terminal or through MySQL itself I still can't connect to phpMyAdmin. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: can you log into mysql through your terminal and run status? Look for the connection line. likely won't help much, but should indicate where in your world this mysql server is running.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that MySQL is enabled in MAMP, and that you have also enabled *"Allow network access to MySQL"* in MAMP's MySQL settings page.

[image: MAMP's allow network access to MySQL setting]

Answer (score 0):

I went to /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php and updated the line $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

from 127.0.0.1 to localhost.